# appengine Email Quota Reduced To 20100 ( 20000 billable ) emails at 2012-12-08

Tags: google-app-engine, email, limit, reduce, quota

I use GoogleAppEngine for my application. 
Billing is enabled and it sends daily newsletter Emails for my company subscribers.
and there was no problem until Dec-08-2012 
I was sending up to 27000 emails per day (there was no limitation)

after this date my account was restricted 
with daily limit (20100 emails per day (20000 billable)).

Can anyone please explain why this limit was set and if it will be increased or decreased in future?

There is no change in documentation

[Google App Engine Quotas Mail](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas?hl=ka#Mail)

but daily sending limit is reduced now.

Thank you.